# Is there a way to control the driver using a weight map?

Tags: rigging

Is there any way to read the weight map value of a given object using the empty object.

You can control the shape key with the distance driver between two empty, but this solution has a serious disadvantage, in the moment when there is more empty, there is no proper mixing of the shape key, analyzing it I came to the conclusion that the best solution would be to use some object, and use its grid and weight maps, exactly their values, I have no idea how to read these values so that you can control them with the controller.

That's exactly what I mean, "https://vimeo.com/246108083" just instead of texture, I want to use waight maps.
" https://d1a9v60rjx2a4v.cloudfront.net/2013/10/02/23_14_46_471_screen1_4.jpg "

I found a similar idea, but the problem was not solved, maybe someone here will know how to solve it.
" https://blenderartists.org/t/driver-based-on-vertex-weights/664337 "